# Tensorflow: Slice Input image and grayscale

Tags: python, image, numpy, matrix, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow and am trying to slice an image to then grayscale it. My code so far looks like this. I am first taking the input, then extract image data into a tensor, then slice the middle part of the image. The weights etc. can be disregarded for this step, just wanted to give the reader context:

```
##############################
#   NETWORK IMPLEMENTATION   #
##############################
tf.reset_default_graph()

########
#Forward

##Inputs
input = tf.placeholder(shape=[210, 160, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
print(input.get_shape())
#inputs = tf.reshape(input, [1, 210, 160, 3])
#print(inputs.get_shape())

##Grayscale
#inputs = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(input, name=None)
#print(inputs.get_shape())

#Slicing
inputs = tf.slice(input, [25, 0, 0], [160, 160, 3])
print(inputs.get_shape())

#Downsample to new dimensions
#inputs = tf.image.decode_jpeg(inputs)
inputs = tf.image.resize_images(inputs, [84, 84]) 
print(inputs.get_shape())
inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [1, -1])
print(inputs.get_shape())

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([84*84, 6], 0.00, 0.01))
Qout = tf.matmul(inputs, W)
predict = tf.argmax(Qout, 1) #why exactly this operation?
```

Whenever I run this, however, I get an error stating:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    inputs = tf.image.resize_images(inputs, [84, 84])
TypeError: resize_images() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I have read the documentation on slicing and resizing, but I am still confused. As said, I'm new to tensorflow, would be grateful for any help :)

I tried commenting out to debug, but I'm not even sure if that caused the problems. I am always getting the above error.

Comment: `input` is `placeholder`, so you can't have second `input = ...`, just change the name of variance

Comment: @xxi what exactly do you mean? (can't recognize any second line with 'input = ..')

Comment: Sorry, I misread all your variance is `input`, didn't notice `inputs`. I just run your code, it work fine, the only problem is size of `W`, i think it is `[84*84*3, 6]` . maybe your example loss something?

Comment: @xxi hmm interesting, then maybe something is wrong with my version of tensorflow or so, thanks a lot for the effort!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Looks like your using an older version of tensorflow and didn't state it though.  To fix your error change it to be like so.

```
    inputs = tf.image.resize_images(inputs, 84, 84)
```

where in this case the first 84 is the new height and the second one is the width.

Old Answer Valid for tensorflow 1.0:
I think your issue is that

```
inputs = tf.image.resize_images(inputs, [84, 84, 3])
```

should be

```
inputs = tf.image.resize_images(inputs, [84, 84])
```

as size should only describe height and width, and should not include number of channels.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the correction, but unfortunately changing this does not help...

Comment: You updated the question with the new error? Also which version of tensorflow are you using? You can see with print(tf.__version__) I updated my answer accordingly